# Cannot publish 3rd Knowledge Base after upgrading pricing tier

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to migrate all our knowledge bases from old to new. On my third knowledge base, I upgraded our pricing tier from F0 to S0 but I still get the following error:
[image]

I tried waiting overnight but that didn't help. Then I tried going back to F0, then back again to S0:
[image]

I still have the same runtime error when publishing my 3rd knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the screenshot of the error you provided, it says it has crossed Azure search Index max limit, so you need to update Azure Search pricing tier.

You are changing management pricing tier, which is responsible for knowledgebase size & count of documents along with calls made.

Update Azure Search pricing Tier, and it will work.

Thanks,
Kasam Shaikh

Comment: I never had that before and it doesn't say on QnA Maker import that I need to get one... I googled it and found that i do indeed need it now: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/ thanks